# What does google CheckCookie link do?

Tags: cookies, authentication, session-cookies

I've found a code which opens this link after logging in to google account programmatically.
What's the purpose this link?

https://www.google.com/accounts/CheckCookie?chtml=LoginDoneHtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
After Successfully logged in this url gets all old cookiees which stored in browser in request header and verify with server and update it if any changes.

generally this cookie always changed during each request 

 1. __utma,
 2. __utmb,
 3. __utmc,
 4. __utmz.
```

to see live demo of changing cookie use firecookie addon in firefox.